Change list of words in Word file, using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word and C#
To change one word in Word file, using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word and C#, I use code similar to:
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        Application application = new Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = application.Documents.Add(pathToFile);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find findObject = application.Selection.Find;

        findObject.ClearFormatting();
        findObject.Text = "{DATA_0}";
        findObject.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
        findObject.Replacement.Text = "Found";
        
        object replaceAll = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
        findObject.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref replaceAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        object filename = pathToTmpFile;
        document.SaveAs2(ref filename);

        document.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        document = null;
        application.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        application = null;

But how can I change several word in single Word file, at once? Using this code several times makes application and whole process very slow... Can you suggest me some solution please?

could you post the slow code (with the loop).
